# Typescript conversion from interface to recursive type throws an Index signature is missing in type error

Tags: typescript

[Live Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOBLAhgG0QL2QI1dAvAFBRQA+UAzsEgHYDmxZUNArgLbYKPnYD2veZDW7MWqVCJY0AJhABmiGhGki4SNJhx4AgvHjIQqhCnRZcEAEoQAxr3jSA3IUKLgCOcmvQ1Jzed36IFAQAB5uMhRQAQYAPD4aZngAfFAA3gC+LjRu8B5esMYJWpY2dtLBYRARUFa29jFUtHQANAXqpsUpGc5ZOXnQAKKV8DRoAJLZ7p7QqYxQyMDUAFyU1Ip0TpmEtjRUUCErQzmjqBN901D4aQvLUADkyHfpTjt7ICvxHea1ZZf7TtteLsBBAAHSoXh0AAUIAAlA4gA)

I have defined a recursive `SerializableRecord` interface that I defined with the help of [recursive type references](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050). **This interface can be changed**.

```ts
type Serializable =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | null
  | undefined
  | SerializableArray
  | SerializableRecord;

interface SerializableArray extends Array<Serializable> {}
interface SerializableRecord extends Record<string, Serializable> {}
```

I have another **imported** interface (which means I can't change it):

```
interface ExternalInterface {
   attr: string;
}
```

Now if I try to do the following I get an error:

```
const x: ExternalInterface = {attr: 'a'};
const y: SerializableRecord = x;
// Throws a TS error: "Index signature is missing in type 'ExternalInterface'"
```

Is there a way to make those two entities compatible, without introducing `any` or `unknown`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is currently by design according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).

The best workaround I know of is to “convert” the interface into a type:

```js
type AsType<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P]; }

const x: ExternalInterface = {attr: 'a'};
const y: SerializableRecord = x as AsType<typeof x>;
```

Another one is to use the object spread syntax,

```js
const y: SerializableRecord = { ...x };
```

but that requires copying the object, which you probably do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, but doesn't satisfy your requirement of not changing the ExternalInterface

```
type ExternalInterface = { attr: string };
const x: ExternalInterface = { attr: 'a' };
const y: SerializableRecord = x;
```

Comment: I know this would work :-) But like I said, I can't change the external interface :-D